# Validate string against allowed values / array of strings

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

In `Yup`, is there any built-in check to validate a string against an array of allowed values? Or do I have to write my own test function for that?

```
const fruit = 'apple';
const allowedFruits = ['orange', 'cherry'];
// I want to check if fruit is one of the allowedFruits. Fruit is coming from a text field / user input.
```

**Update:**
I want to stress that the question is about the `Yup` validation library, not how to do it in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
const selectedFruit = "apple";
const allowedFruits = ['orange', 'cherry'];
const isInAllowedFruits = allowedFruits.some(fruit => fruit === selectedFruit)
```

Just use the boolean `isInAllowedFruits`.

Comment: thank, but I need to know how to do it with `Yup`.

Answer (score -1):

**Try Using:**

```js
const fruit = 'apple';
const fruit1 = 'orange';
const allowedFruits = ['orange', 'cherry'];
console.log(allowedFruits.includes(fruit));
console.log(allowedFruits.includes(fruit1));
```

Comment: thank, but I need to know how to do it with `Yup`.